# Compare if DateTime values are "between" specific hours

Tags: c#, datetime

How to compare current time with another time..

```
System.DateTime.Now.Hour
```

This is for get cuurent hour.
What I want is if the time is in between

```
7 AM                 to            02:59 PM  //Do something
03:00 PM             to            10:59 PM  //Do something
11:00 PM             to            06:59 AM  //Do something
```

Please give me any ideas..?

Answer (score 6):

You may use  **[DateTime.TimeOfDay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx)** property to compare the time with the current time.

```
TimeSpan startTime = new TimeSpan(7,0,0);
TimeSpan endTime = new TimeSpan(2, 59, 0);

if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay >= startTime &&
    DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay <= endTime)
{
    //in range
}
else
{
    //not in range. 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do arithmetic operations on DateTime, and it returns a timespan.

```
        DateTime d1 = new DateTime(2012, 12, 12, 5, 5, 5);
        DateTime d2 = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan();
        ts = d2 - d1;
```

Comment: So how can said TimeSpan be used in a conditional? Also, what if I only know "7 AM", but not necessarily which day? Do I have to create a new DateTime just to check if it is "between" some values?